# How to get the number in a message when click in the textView Fragment class

Tags: java, android

How to get the data in a message when click in the textView from Fragment
i Work  on android studio
I hope to get the code with all thanks
How to get the data in a message when click in the textView from Fragment
i Work  on android studio
I hope to get the code with all thanks

```js
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CALL_LOG" />
```

Gratefully

class[image]

```js
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.content.CursorLoader;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.CallLog;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;

/**
 * Created by TAREQALEID1 on 09/06/2017.
 */

public class Tab1 extends Fragment {
    View rootView;
    boolean mDualPane;
    int mCurCheckPosition = 0;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        Button    btnCheckFalAction  ;

        rootView=inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab1,container,false);

        ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> callLog=getCallLog();
        CustomCallLogListAdapter adapter=new CustomCallLogListAdapter(getActivity(),R.layout.row_call_log_layout,callLog);
        ListView    list_calllog=(ListView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.list_calllog);
        list_calllog.setAdapter(adapter);




        btnCheckFalAction = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.button2); // you have to use rootview object..
        btnCheckFalAction.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Hello World", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });

        return rootView;
    }
    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        ListView    list_calllog=(ListView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.list_calllog);




        list_calllog.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position,
                                    long arg3) {
Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Item clicked : " + position, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }

        });

    }

    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    public ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> getCallLog()
    {
        ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> callLog=new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();
        CursorLoader cursorLoader=new CursorLoader(getActivity(), CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);
        Cursor cursor=cursorLoader.loadInBackground();
        if(cursor.moveToFirst())
        {
            while (cursor.moveToNext())
            {
                HashMap<String,String> hashMap=new HashMap<String, String>();
                hashMap.put(CallLog.Calls.NUMBER, cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.NUMBER)));
                hashMap.put(CallLog.Calls.DATE, cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.DATE)));
                hashMap.put(CallLog.Calls.DURATION, cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.DURATION)));
                callLog.add(hashMap);
            }
        }
        return callLog;
    }


}
```

```js
import android.content.Context;
import android.provider.CallLog;
import android.text.format.DateFormat;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.HashMap;



public class CustomCallLogListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<HashMap<String,String>>
{
    private ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> callLogData;
    private Context context;
    private int resource;
    private View view;
    private Holder holder;
    private HashMap<String,String> hashMap;
    public CustomCallLogListAdapter(Context context, int resource,ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> objects)
    {
        super(context, resource, objects);
        this.context=context;
        this.resource=resource;
        this.callLogData=objects;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {

        LayoutInflater inflater=(LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        view=inflater.inflate(resource, parent,false);

        holder=new Holder();
        holder.text_number=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.text_calllog_number);
        holder.text_date=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.text_calllog_date);
        holder.text_time=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.text_calllog_time);

        hashMap=callLogData.get(position);

        Date date=new Date(Long.parseLong(hashMap.get(CallLog.Calls.DATE)));
        java.text.DateFormat dateFormat=DateFormat.getDateFormat(context);
        java.text.DateFormat timeformat=DateFormat.getTimeFormat(context);


        holder.text_number.setText(hashMap.get(CallLog.Calls.NUMBER));
        holder.text_time.setText(timeformat.format(date));
        holder.text_date.setText(dateFormat.format(date));

        return view;
    }

    public class Holder
    {
        TextView text_number;
        TextView text_date;
        TextView text_time;
    }

}
```

```js
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.TabLayout;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

public class Getfolder1 extends AppCompatActivity {

    /**
     * The {@link android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter} that will provide
     * fragments for each of the sections. We use a
     * {@link FragmentPagerAdapter} derivative, which will keep every
     * loaded fragment in memory. If this becomes too memory intensive, it
     * may be best to switch to a
     * {@link android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter}.
     */
    private SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;

    /**
     * The {@link ViewPager} that will host the section contents.
     */
    private ViewPager mViewPager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_getfolder1);

        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        // Create the adapter that will return a fragment for each of the three
        // primary sections of the activity.
        mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

        // Set up the ViewPager with the sections adapter.
        mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.container);
        mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);

        TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);

        mViewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(tabLayout));
        tabLayout.addOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.ViewPagerOnTabSelectedListener(mViewPager));


    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_getfolder1, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    /**
     * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
     */
    public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {
        /**
         * The fragment argument representing the section number for this
         * fragment.
         */
        private static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";

        public PlaceholderFragment() {
        }

        /**
         * Returns a new instance of this fragment for the given section
         * number.
         */
        public static PlaceholderFragment newInstance(int sectionNumber) {
            PlaceholderFragment fragment = new PlaceholderFragment();
            Bundle args = new Bundle();
            args.putInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, sectionNumber);
            fragment.setArguments(args);
            return fragment;
        }


    }

    /**
     * A {@link FragmentPagerAdapter} that returns a fragment corresponding to
     * one of the sections/tabs/pages.
     */
    public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

        public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
switch (position){
    case 0:
        Tab1 tab1= new Tab1();
        return tab1;

    case 1:
        Tab2 tab2= new Tab2();
        return tab2;


}
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            // Show 3 total pages.
            return 2;
        }
    }
}
```

```js
<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->
```

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/lyt1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView5"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:text="TextView"
            tools:ignore="HardcodedText"
            tools:text="مرحبا" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:text="Button"
            tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/list_calllog"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

```js
<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->
```

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/main_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="imagingstudents2.com.imagingstudents2.Getfolder1">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/appbar_padding_top"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"
            app:title="@string/app_name">

        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <android.support.design.widget.TabItem
                android:id="@+id/tabItem"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/tab_text_1" />

            <android.support.design.widget.TabItem
                android:id="@+id/tabItem2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/tab_text_2" />



        </android.support.design.widget.TabLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

```js
row_call_log_layout.xml
```

```js
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/const1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text_calllog_number"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@android:color/holo_orange_light"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/lyott2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/text_calllog_number">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/text_calllog_date"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                tools:ignore="NestedWeights" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/text_calllog_time"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1" />
        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add an OnclickListener to the holder.text_number:

```
String message = "";  
holder.text_number.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                message = textview.getText().toString();
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Message : " + message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }
        });
```

Now do whatever you want with the `message` String.

Comment: Thank you very much but in which class

Comment: Is it possible to more detail with respect and appreciation

Comment: I've been reading your code, bro and i think i found out the issue, im gna edit my answer ok.

Comment: try adding the code from my answer in CustomCallLogListAdapter's getView() method, before return view;

Answer (score 1):

```
    final TextView text_number2=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.text_calllog_number);
    holder.text_number.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            Toast.makeText( context, "" +  text_number2.getText().toString() , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
    });
```

Ten days I look for the answer .....Wadaane .... Thank you very much